# Uploading Video to youtube with Title, description and tags from app-Android

Tags: android, android-intent, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing an app in which the user can be allowed to upload the videos from his gallery to youtube. I tried using Intents,but i could not prefill the Title and description using intent.

Then i tried youtube api for uploading. I referred https://github.com/sohnkh/YoutubeUploadAndroidSampleV3 . But in this the tags and description are hardcoded. I want the user to see the description and allow him to change. Is there any simple way using intents. Can some one please give me a clear explanation on this.

Thanks.